# Why jquery.focus() doesn't work on my bootstrap popup modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use require.js. jquery.focus() works on normal html site but doesn't work on bootstrap popup modal. I make a search form which contains this textbox.

```
define(["common"], function(common) {
    function init() {
        initFocus();
    }

    function initFocus() {
        $("#p001SearchIDTxt").focus();
    }

    return {
        "init": init
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to how HTML5 defines its semantics, the autofocus HTML attribute has no effect in Bootstrap modals. To achieve the same effect, use some custom JavaScript:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#p001SearchIDTxt").focus();
})
```

Source:
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/